# "globalprocesserfld" will damage your computer

Tags: macbook-pro, error

since the day before yesterday I got following error:

"GlobalProcesserfld" will damage your computer.

[image]

Do you know what that is?
When I click on "OK", the pop-up appears back.
Also "Show in Finder" doesn't show anything and the popup appears back in few seconds.

Thank you!

Comment: https://malwaretips-com.translate.goog/blogs/remove-globalprocesser/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=it&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: Browser based malware. Clean your browser history and cookies

Answer (score 2):

I ran [MalwareBytes](http://malwarebytes.com) (free for personal use) to clean this up on a Mac today.