# Having problems with Macbook Pro getting interrupting message from system about "AnaylzerWindowfld", how can I stop this?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder

I have a Macbook Pro from a friend and it's repeatedly showing the same message, "AnaylzerWindowfld will damage your computer. This file was downloaded on an unknown date." The only two options I have to respond are "Ok" and "Show in Finder". Neither do anything. And the message will reappear about 3-5 seconds later.

I cannot find this file after looking inside the applications, documents and trash. The process doesn't show up in Force Quit but will periodically show up in the Activity Monitor but disappears quickly. Tried using the "killall" command on the file name but the console cannot find the process. I cannot find any information on this file on the internet so I'm really hoping for any scrap of help.

Any help you can give will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466643/globalprocesserfld-will-damage-your-computer - different virus, same fix.